# How do I change default text in a Qt lineEdit by entering data into the running frame in order to re-run functions with the new value?

Tags: python, qt

I am new to Python, and even more new to PyQt4. (I've created a similar GUI with wxPython, but I can't make this work.) I've spent hours trying to figure this out, and I've tried so many tips from searches here and elsewhere, including the instruction docs, that I'm dizzy.

The window I created in Qt Designer is supposed to allow the user to enter data in QLineEdit boxes, and that data is then used in some functions to do some math and plot some graphs. To make it easy for the user - I think - I've put default values in the frame when it runs. I do not know how to allow the user to dynamically set new values (i.e., different from the default). I've tried chasing things back with a global variable to see where things go wrong, but I can't figure it out.

I've created a much smaller version of what I'm doing (to keep it short), and the issue is the same.

Here's a picture of the frame to help if I've failed to explain this well:
[Frame screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egREh.png)

And here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'TestWindow2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

my_global_var = 100

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    global my_global_var

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(514, 363)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 501, 31))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("formLayoutWidget"))
        self.formLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtGui.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("formLayout"))
        self.enterHereLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.enterHereLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("enterHereLabel"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.enterHereLabel)
        self.enterHereLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.enterHereLineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("enterHereLineEdit"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.enterHereLineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 461, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 514, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        global my_global_var
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.enterHereLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter here:", None))
        self.enterHereLineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "100", None))
        """ ^ Code created by Qt Designer with the default value of 100 """
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushThisButton", None))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

        x = str(self.enterHereLineEdit.text()) # Seeing if I can get the value
        print("x = {0}".format(x)) # This correctly prints the default value of 100
        my_global_var = x
        print("My global var = {0}".format(my_global_var)) # Correctly -> 100

    def MyFunction(self, MainWindow):
        global my_global_var

        print("My var = {0}".format(my_global_var)) # prints 100
        a = int(my_global_var)
        y = a+20
        print(y) # correctly prints 120

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    global my_global_var

    def __init__(self, parent=None, f=QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, f)

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've left the global variables and comments to show how things work. What do I need to change / do to make the user's frame entry update the calculations? (When I click the button, I get the same results regardless of whether I change the default value.)

Comment: Not sure to understand, but I think you don't need a global variable. Simply read the value from the QLineEdit in MyFunction (a = int(self.enterHereLineEdit.text()))

Comment: You seem to understand it, because this works. I knew it would be something simple that I overlooked. I'll see if I can get it running in the real code (which is much longer than the example I posted). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabio's comment has the answer, but an option to accept it as answered didn't appear (maybe because it was a comment and not an answer??), so I'm "answering" to mark this as answered, but it was his response that is the answer, which I'll quote for simplicity, highlighting the key code:

> Not sure to understand, but I think you don't need a global variable. Simply 
>   read the value from the QLineEdit in MyFunction 
>   **(a = int(self.enterHereLineEdit.text()))** – Fabio

Thanks!